# Save/Load System in Python Text-Based RPG

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a save/load system in my Python RPG, but can only partially figure out how to get this done. I've seen other questions asked on this topic, but none of them really fit for what I am doing.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.base_defe = 0
        self.weap = "Rusty Sword"
        self.wbow = "None"
        self.armH = "Worn Helmet"
        self.armB = "Worn Shirt"
        self.armA = "Worn Gloves"
        self.armL = "Worn Pants"
        self.armF = "Worn Boots"
        self.gold = 1000
        self.orichalcum = 0 
        self.base_stre = 1
        self.base_magi = 1
        self.base_rang = 1
        self.maxmana = 100
        self.mana = self.maxmana
        self.level = 1
        self.exp = 0
        self.maxexp = 100
        self.expdiff = 50
        self.pots = 0
        self.arrows = 0
        self.q1c = False
        self.q2c = False
        self.q3c = False
        self.q1 = False
        self.q2 = False
        self.q3 = False
        self.QuestActive = False
        self.qtitle = "None"
        self.maxhealth = 100 + self.defe
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.inventory = ["Rusty Sword", 
                          "Worn Shirt", 
                          "Worn Pants", 
                          "Worn Boots",
                          "Worn Helmet",
                          "Worn Gloves"]
        self.spells = []
```

I also have a variable called PlayerIG that represents the player, but it is set in a function, so I keep getting messages like PlayerIG is not defined when I try to load the game. I have tried to create a save/load system using pickle and putting everything in a dictionary. Saving it works fine, but loading it certainly doesn't, because whenever I try to load it all, the variables are reset. I can't figure out how to get this working properly, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

The part that has given me the most problems is:

```
def name():
    os.system('clear')
    PlayerIG = Player(raw_input("What is your name?"))
    print ("Prints story")
```

The reason is PlayerIG is meant to represent the player but whenever I tried to load the save file with:

```
def load():
    os.system('clear')
    with open('savefile', 'rb') as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)
    print "Loaded last save state..."
    option = raw_input(" ")
    #data is equal to PlayerIG
```

It gives me errors such as PlayerIG does not exist or whenever I set PlayerIG outside of the function it sets PlayerIG to the default stats and it loads the game setting all of the players stats to default instead of loading the stats they have saved.

Comment: Just post the part of your program that does whatever you're trying to do, not unrelated code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What I'm trying to do is get these variables saved into a text file and then loaded into my game. "Create a save/load system with these variables"

Comment: Did you look at any other StackOverflow questions on this topic? This is a frequently asked question.

Comment: I have but they haven't worked.

Comment: Please take the time to read the help section on how to ask questions and get help. What questions have you read? _What_ hasn't worked? Just saying "I tried stuff but it didn't work" isn't helping anyone help you.

Comment: I updated my question trying to give as much info about what isn't working in my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to make one correction to your class definition: `self.maxhealth = 100 + self.defe` should be `self.maxhealth = 100 + self.base_defe` (I presume that is what you meant).

Here is a test that runs and seems to work fine in python 3.4.2 on OS X:

```
import pickle

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.base_defe = 0
        self.weap = "Rusty Sword"
        self.wbow = "None"
        self.armH = "Worn Helmet"
        self.armB = "Worn Shirt"
        self.armA = "Worn Gloves"
        self.armL = "Worn Pants"
        self.armF = "Worn Boots"
        self.gold = 1000
        self.orichalcum = 0 
        self.base_stre = 1
        self.base_magi = 1
        self.base_rang = 1
        self.maxmana = 100
        self.mana = self.maxmana
        self.level = 1
        self.exp = 0
        self.maxexp = 100
        self.expdiff = 50
        self.pots = 0
        self.arrows = 0
        self.q1c = False
        self.q2c = False
        self.q3c = False
        self.q1 = False
        self.q2 = False
        self.q3 = False
        self.QuestActive = False
        self.qtitle = "None"
        self.maxhealth = 100 + self.base_defe
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.inventory = ["Rusty Sword", 
                          "Worn Shirt", 
                          "Worn Pants", 
                          "Worn Boots",
                          "Worn Helmet",
                          "Worn Gloves"]
        self.spells = []

p = Player('Fred')
p.exp = 100
p.gold = 5000

with open('fred.player', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(p, f)

with open('fred.player', 'rb') as f:
    p2 = pickle.load(f)

print('Loaded player "%s" with %d exp and %d gold.' % (p2.name, p2.exp, p2.gold))
```

Comment: So the code works! The only thing wrong with mine is right after it loads and goes to the main menu it displays stats as default. I know that the code works because right after it loads I make it display stats like it would in the menu.

Comment: Ok I figured it out I just had to set PlayerIG in the load function to global.